# Strange behaviour of selenium with python. Cannot see truly visible element

Tags: python, selenium

When I ckick at `edit profile link` I get a page with my profile info. There I want to set my hometown. Everything is ok until I try to submit it. Selenium tells me, there is no such element. But it is there! in developer tools I can even see that it is not `display:block`. What's the problem? Is it openning in a new frame or smth else? I cannot find a save button. I tried `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element.click().perform()` but it gave me nothing... `can anyone explain me how to click the button? the same buttons are in all Edit Forms there...
UPD:
It sees text input and ajax form to choose from suggested options, but not the button in the same form... I cannot understand.
here is my code:

```
def _update_hometown(self):
    try:
        curr_city = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, u"current_city")
        curr_city.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, u"fbProfileBlankStateIcon").click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, u"edit_hometown")))
        input_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, u"edit_hometown").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, u"inputtext")
        input_field.send_keys(u"Moscow")
        input_field.click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, u"text")))
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, u"text").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "save").click()

    except ElementNotVisibleException as NVE:
        print "Button not visible! {0}".format(NVE.msg)
        self._stack_trace(sys.exc_info())
    except TimeoutException as TE:
        print "Timeout failure. {0}".format(TE.msg)

    except NoSuchElementException as nse:
        print 'Error. Element not found! {0}'.format(nse.msg)
        import traceback
        type_, value_, trace_ = sys.exc_info()
        print traceback.format_tb(trace_)
    except:
        print "Something went wrong."
        import traceback
        type_, value_, trace_ = sys.exc_info()
        print type_, "\t", value_
        print traceback.format_tb(trace_)
```

Here is source of this form, grabbed from dev tools:
[Link to pastebin. facebook form source](http://pastebin.com/KRynsc4q)
[Link to patebin. My code](http://pastebin.com/JxujtdM1)
UPD: `driver.window_handles` returns only one window.

Comment: check if its inside an iframe. if its inside a frame you have to change frame in selenium

Comment: Nope... It's a form, loaded via ajax, afetr I click a link. I've added form source grabbed from dev tools

Comment: could it be that the element is not visible when you hit the page, but it gets visible when it downloads some data?

Comment: @FooBarUser it's loaded as a form. I can see the input, but not the button? I fill the text input and even can click at ajax dropdown. But not the button. When I look at the page's source I can see it. When I click to see css rules, I cannot find it invisible.

Comment: strange your html looks ok to me

Comment: @FooBarUser exactly! that's ok... I do not understand, how can it be possible to work with input in form, and get problems with button. `submit()` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did't get what was wrong... I've tried to rewrite all `find_element` with `XPATH` and it worked. Pretty strange though.